# Network connection disappears in VMWare Workstation 16 Player spontaneously

Tags: networking, vmware-workstation

I have Ubuntu 18.04 host, running Windows 10 guest with VMWare Workstation 16 Player version 16.1.2. My problem is that I'm unable to get a stable internet connection. I have tried two setups, NAT and bridged. Both of them showed same problem. Sometimes internet connection spontaneously disappears from guest (despite host os still being able to access internet) and reappears after some period of time, from 10 to 30 seconds usually.

How can I achieve stable internet connection without spontaneous breaks on my guest os?

Comment: I have Ubuntu 20 running on VMware Workstation 16.1.2 and the internet connection in Ubuntu is very stable. Consider (a) upgrading VMware Workstation to the current .2 version just recently released and (b) fully updating Ubuntu and possibly updating it to V20.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "internet connection disappears"?

Comment: The connection icon on the tray turns into a globe and when I click on it, it says that i'm not connected to any network

Comment: There is too little info to do a troubleshooting. Try to setup a second VM (clean install) and see if it shows the same symptoms (at the same time) to see if it's an issue with the host. Did you research this problem yet? What have you found?

Comment: @Albin right now i'm not capable of setupping a second VM, but i assume it's probably a host issue. do you have any idea what it could be in that case?

Comment: Unfortunately no, as I said there is too little information and there are too many causes that could come from a system. You could check if it's limited to a routing issue, for example by pinging another device in the same subnet (on the same LAN)...  but that's just poking around in the dark, with too specific pokes...  so unless you get lucky you won't get around installing a fresh VM (thus eliminating a lot of causes at the same time).